# Знаете ли вы где скачать сборку eclipse с sdk + adt?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, ide, железо

я начинающий, хотел написать простенькую программу для android, но железо не позволяет пользоваться android studio. Я решил скачать eclipse. Всё бы хорошо, но там нужно слишком много всего скачивать чтобы комфортно работать. Наткнулся на одну хорошую сборку со всеми инструментами, я работал бы там но слишком старый sdk. Знаете ли вы где скачать нормальную сборку или что можно сделать с этой?

Comment: Если разбиратсья что нужно докачивать - проблема, то зачем вообще использовать эклипс? Поставить Андроид Студию, она сама все сделает

Comment: " хотел написать простенькую программу для android, но железо не позволяет пользоваться android studio "

Comment: @AndreyKubyshenko боюсь, что эклипс еще более требователен к железу. В своё время андроид студия была по сути плагином в эклипс, и работала заметно медленее.

Comment: Что там за железо такое, что АС не тянет?

Comment: 2gb RAM, intel celeron какой-то, а видеокарты как таковой нету). Как бы вы разрабатывали?

Comment: О, у меня как раз похожий ноутбук 2007 года. АС там работает (на линуксе). Вот эмулятор не работает, но это не проблема. Если не работает последняя версия, скачаете какую-нибудь постарше.

Comment: @AndreyKubyshenko можно попробовать с системой поиграться, думаю есть супер лайтовые линукс дистрибутивы, а еще вроде винда lite выходила, не знаю, вышла уже или еще нет.